# Connect to Implicit SSL/TLS (port 990) using Paramiko?

Tags: ftp, sftp, paramiko, ftps, fileshare

Is there a way to use Paramiko, to connect to sharefile.com as SFTP?

For example using this approach, I can connect to SFTP (the one I created myself in Linux):

```python
from paramiko import SSHConfig, SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy, AuthenticationException

def connect(self):
    for rec in self:

        with closing(SSHClient()) as ssh:
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            try:
                login = rec.login_id
                ssh.connect(login.host, port=login.port, username=login.user, password=login.passwd)
            except socket.gaierror:
               raise ValidationError(_("Name or service '%s' not known") % (login.host))
            except AuthenticationException:
               raise Warning(_("Bad username or password"))                    
            with closing(ssh.open_sftp()) as sftp:
                #do something
```

But If I try to connect using login info for fileshare.com, it does not work. In fileshare.com it says you can connect two ways:

Security:   Standard (Port 21) or Implicit SSL/TLS (Port 990)
FTP Server: company.sharefileftp.com
User name:  username    or    username_id
Password:   (your ShareFile password)

So If I try to connect using port 990, I will get either *Connection timed* out (after some time) or this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 306, in connect
    t.start_client()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 465, in start_client
    raise e
SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

The only way I was able to connect to it, was using Ubuntu built in GUI to connect so FTP, using:

```
ftp//:user@company.sharefileftp.com
```

If I used `sftp`, it would not connect (I guess it uses default port 22)

I also tried to connect from terminal:

```
ftp user@company.sharefileftp.com
Name or service not known
```

```
sftp -oPort=990 user@company.sharefileftp.com
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Secure FTP ([FTP over TLS/SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS)) is not the [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol).

The SFTP runs over SSH.

You cannot use Paramiko to connect to the FTP, neither a plain FTP nor over the TLS/SSL.

Use the `FTP_TLS` class from the [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) for FTP over TLS/SSL in Python.

Comment: Thanks, then I'll try to use this libary instead.